# Impedance of JK flip flops

Tags: impedance, flipflop

Lets assume we get a square wave signal output from an astable multivibrator. Can we connect the output as input of the clock signal in order to create a digital counter with some specific frequency without altering the frequency of the square wave produced by the astable multivibrator? What is the impedance of a JK flip flop?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feFhnF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please post the schematic of your circuit and a link to the datasheet of the FF.

Comment: Impedance is measured between two points. It is unclear between which points you want to know the impedance. Also a flip-flop is a switching circuit and it behaves in a **very non-linear** way. Impedance assumes **a linear relation** between voltage and current. A flip flop does not have such a relation. Even if you knew the impedance, it is pointless information. If you want to use a clock generated by an oscillator then common practice is to add a **buffer** to its output so that the oscillator will not be influenced by the load as the buffer will drive the load.

Comment: Usually a gate can drive up to three similar gates without much loss of performance. This clock you are generating would feed how many gates? This is the reason clock lines are driven with clock buffers.

Comment: it will feed 12 JK flip flops

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie so use a mosfet buffer?

Comment: Ok i will post a schematic

Comment: *so use a mosfet buffer?* A flip-flop is a **digital/logic** circuit so stop thinking in  **analog circuits**, think gates, NANS, OR etc.... What do we use in logic as a buffer. Not an inverter but... I stongly advise you to search for "CMOS logic circuit" in Google search and then press the images tab to see many **examples** of logic circuits.

Comment: I have added  a circuit maybe it is clearer now\

Comment: No because you don't tell us what type the Flip-flops are. TTL, LS, CMOS??

Comment: They are CMOS logic flip flops

Answer (score 1):

The input impedance of the CLK signal of those JK circuits is 100 M Ohm or more. The input circuit is in fact the GATE of a MOSFET which shows an extremely high impedance.

Those JK circuits will not load your astable multivibrator analog circuit.

Comment: How much is the capacitance of the gate-source?I suspect very low so the time costant will be much less than the frequency of the square wave->no problems?

Comment: Don't forget capacitance. CMOS F-F input capacitance is around 3.5 pF.

Comment: I wanted to keep the answer simple and didn't want to talk about displacement current that flows in the gate at high frequencies.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a modulu counter " Ring counter " it is simply a counter that it's output is the clock signal divided by the number of the flipflops used in the counter and you can divide the clock to any frequency you want for your counter.

correct me if i'm wrong